# Set Dynamic URL in served HTML page by Express

Tags: javascript, html, docker, express

Im running an Express API inside docker container, and one of my routes serves the user a HTML page.

```
app.get('/trilateration/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname,'trilateration','/Trilateration.html'));

});
```

This page has its javascript code, and this code calls the express API to get data. Im setting the  express server api in JS like this:

```
var serverHost='http://rtlsdatabase:3014'
var urlpos =  serverHost + "/pos/";
var urlrpi = serverHost + "/rpi/";
var urltooling = serverHost + "/tooling/";
var urlBlueprint = serverHost + "/blueprint/";
var urlDimensions = serverHost + "/dimensions/"
```

Im using a .env file to pass variables to the docker container and use it with Express, but the HTML page and javascript code can not consume it.

How can i pass the server URL dynamically to this "serverHost" variable? I want to setup it in .env file or even get it in another way, since the url host is the same server that is serving that page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How's the javascript added to the page? Are you adding it with a script tag? @alosbh

Comment: @fortunee yes. a <script> tag
```<script type="text/javascript" src="JSTrilat.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the server environment variables from the browser/client environment.

To achieve what you:

1. The browser/client has to make a GET request to the server in order to get that value.
   The javascript code in the HTML can make the request with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) like this example code shown below:

```js
fetch('http://url-to-express-server/data')
  .then(res => res.json())
  // the data here is the value sent from the server
  .then((data => console.log(data))
```

2. The express server must expose an endpoint that returns the piece of data from its environment variable. The example code below defines the endpoint as `/data` but it can be anything descriptive.

```js
app.get('/data', (req, res) => res.json(process.env.serverHost));
```

NB: Ensure you have that environment variable in your env file and you're using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to read the environment variables.

Don't hesitate to ask any questions